# Find line number and content of a line and then find open same line number in another file JAVA

Tags: java

I got this code to open up a file and getting the line number, but if I want to open up another file where the content is not the same as the first file and find the same line number, how can I do that the best way? Where do I go from here?
  I'm new to this site and to Java so please go easy on me...

```
public class c {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        File file =new File("one.txt");
        Scanner in = null;

        try {
            int counter = 0;
            in = new Scanner(file);
            while(in.hasNext()) {
                counter++;
                String line=in.nextLine();
                if(line.contains("umbrella")) {
                    System.out.println(line + " line: " + counter);
                }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just open the other file, and read the lines and increment a counter (counter2) until your counter2 reaches your counter-Variable (from above code-snippet). You also have to notice if the file hasn't ended.

The Code is has many similar Elements like the one you already used in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would depend on the context at which you are developing.  You could just create additional instances of File and Scanner classes to operate on a different file as you already done in your code and mentioned in comment already.

Another method would be to create a class that would process this for you.  In this case you could use this class for an unlimited number of files that you need to accomplish the same.

```
public class FileLineCounter {

    public FileLineCounter( String filename)
    {
    try
    {
        f = new File(filename);
        s = new Scanner(f);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public int getLineNumber( String item)
{
    counter = 0;
    while( s.hasNext())
    {
        counter++;
        String line = s.nextLine();
        if (line.contains(item))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

    private File f;
    private Scanner s;
    private int counter;
};

package FileUtil;
import FileUtil.FileLineCounter;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String file1 = "one.txt";
    String file2 = "two.txt";
    FileLineCounter f1 = new FileLineCounter(file1);
    FileLineCounter f2 = new FileLineCounter(file2);

    System.out.println( file1 + " line : " + f1.getLineNumber("umbrella"));
    System.out.println( file2 + " line : " + f2.getLineNumber("umbrella"));
}
}
```